# Making predictions / Loading model in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: keras, tensorflow, prediction

I use TensorFlow/Keras on a daily basis to make predictions for a project. Everything works fine but I was getting regular warnings about the transition to TensorFlow 2.0 and I thought this week I would finally make sure my code works in the new version of the library as well. I did not encounter any problems during training or saving a model, but when it comes to making predictions I got the following warning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training.
>   Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least
>   `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 10 batches). You may
>   need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

Turns out it still does the prediction as expected, but the warning slows down the process considerably. I was able to overcome this by passing `steps=1` argument to `model.predict()`, but this seems like a roundabout way of doing things, which was not needed in the previous version of TensorFlow.

I wonder if I am missing something trivial here. Also, it seems like TensorFlow now fails to figure out that I am doing prediction not training, which also was not an issue before. On a related note, it was probably in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=stable#predict) before as well but I never thought about the `batch_size` argument in `model.predict()` and the purpose it serves.

**Update:**

Now that Google Colab changed their default version to TensorFlow 2, I decided the give it another shot. Now, the code is still entirely the same, but there is an error when I try to load a model:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Error in loading the saved optimizer state. As a
>   result, your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer.

There is an open question on TensorFlow github page on this issue:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37968

I will update again when it is resolved.

Comment: Can you share your some of the code. Also check following link and see if it solves your issue : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25254.                                            In the link mentioned the similar error happened in different tensorflow version. I guess the error is irrespective of the error

Comment: I saw that post on github before but my issue is during prediction not training. And sure, I will share the code later. I did not share it at first because everything works fine in TensorFlow 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in TF 2.1. It has something to do with the shape/ type of the input, namely the query. In my case, I solved the problem as follows: (My model takes 3 inputs)

```
x = [[test_X[0][0]], [test_X[1][0]], [test_X[2][0]]]
MODEL.predict(x)
```

Output:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training.
>   Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least
>   `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 7 batches). You may
>   need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

**array([[2.053718]], dtype=float32)**

**Solution:**

```
x = [np.array([test_X[0][0]]), np.array([test_X[1][0]]), np.array([test_X[2][0]])]
MODEL.predict(x)
```

Output:

**array([[2.053718]], dtype=float32)**